# Preventing specifying values in a column

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to prevent specifying explicit values in a column?  The identity attribute prevents specifying explicit values (as long as IDENTITY_INSERT is off), which is the type of behavior I want.

```
create table testguid (
    ID uniqueidentifier default newsequentialid() not null primary key
    ,somedate datetime
)
```

[constraint or trigger here?]

```
insert into testguid (somedate) values (getdate()) -- this is ok
insert into testguid (ID, somedate) values (newid(), getdate()) -- this is not ok
```

I want the database to insert values, but I want to prevent any way of specifying them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an INSTEAD OF TRIGGER to basically re-write the INSERT statement, leaving out the ID column.

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.testguid_beforeinsert
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT dbo.testguid(somedate --, other columns
    ) SELECT GETDATE() --, other columns
    FROM inserted;
END
GO
```

Probably want something similar for UPDATE, too.

Comment: That's the right idea, and I should have said this before, but I want to prevent it by returning an error (and rolling back the command).

Comment: I don't know that you'll be able to do that. The `inserted` pseudo-table will contain a value whether it was specified by the user or not, and I think it will be tough to determine whether it is in your `newsequentialid` sequence or not. If you want to prevent people from specifying this column, why are you allowing them to write insert statements? The right way to control this is to take away their insert rights on the table, and make them go through a stored procedure that doesn't accept a parameter for that column.